# How to create AWS CloudFront signed url for s3 video using javascript sdk without NodeJs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-sdk-js

I have some videos in my **aws S3 bucket** , I want to play these videos using jwplayer with **CloudFront signed URLs .**

I have created signed URLs **using aws PHP sdk and its working fine.**
But, **I want the same thing with aws javascript sdk , without using any nodeJs module** , Need simple javascript script with HTML .

Please share suggestion , if anyone done this thing .

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation to generate SignedURL with Javascript.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

Yo need to share your private key, which is dangerous and not an acceptable practice.

**Cloudfront Signed URL SDK for Javascript:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFront/Signer.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have already checked this, But I need cloudFront Signed URL .
Same like this check this url ,https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/cloudfront-signed-url.html  but using javascript SDK

Comment: There is a separate package for cloudfront signer. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

A cloudfront signed url requires you to use your private key. In order to create signed urls on the client side you would need to disclose that private key. Disclosing a private key is never a good thing.

So in simple terms, you can't use a client side script to generate the signed url.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the signed URL's you only need to place it to the player setting.
Check [this](https://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/questions/6062728-amazon-cloudfront-streaming-with-signed-urls)

Edit: Should be easy to integrate.

Comment: I need to generate signed URL with CloudFront .