# How to generate Cloudfront signed url on client side using aws-sdk?

Tags: reactjs, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using ReactJs on the frontend, I just tried to generate a cloudfront signed url through AWS.CLOUDFRONT.SIGNER class using getSignedUrl() method, but it says "createSign is not implemented in the browser".

Please tell me if this is the right approach to do so, I want to stream a video from Aws in my React app, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createSign is not implemented in the browser` is correct. This is an operation that requires authentication, so if your credentials (such as your access key) is in your web application, then that key will be exposed to any client that loads the page.

You should create a back-end service that conceals this key, and then expose endpoints on that service to create and return the signed URL.

See this [similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889208/how-to-create-aws-cloudfront-signed-url-for-s3-video-using-javascript-sdk-withou).

```
(client)                      (backend service)                 (aws)
    |   POST /create-signed-url       |                           |
    |===============================>>|                           |
    |                                 | aws-sdk getSignedUrl()    |
    |                                 |=========================>>|
    |                                 |                           |
    |                                 |   new signed url          |
    |                                 |<<=========================|
    |          signed url             |                           |
    |<<===============================|                           |
    |                                 |                           |
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, So you mean to say that it is not a good practice to generate a signed url on the frontend and also it can't be done?

Comment: I'm not saying it _can't_ be done, but I would highly recommend against it. The key you would use to authenticate with AWS would be easily stolen and, depending on the permissions of the user that key is for, someone could incur outstanding costs (easily thousands of dollars) to your AWS account. See [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/what-to-do-if-you-inadvertently-expose-an-aws-access-key/) article from AWS that details the importance of these keys and what to do if you ever expose one.

Comment: Appreciate your help man! One last thing, Can you tell me what approach can be used to do this from client side(Just for knowledge purpose).

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. The AWS SDK is building some sort of request under the hood that gets sent to AWS. If it's a simple REST API then you could try sending a similar request. It would probably take less time to stand up a simple [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) REST API where you can then use the [`aws-sdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) library. In that environment (Node.js), the `getSignedUrl()` method would be implemented.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi, How about if we store the private key and access key id in the env file? Would it be secure that way?